# Bundle exec jekyll serve: builds a page2 folder with index.html

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

### The problem

I'm running into a conflict error and a strange issue where my Homepage title is modified and "- Page 2" appears in the tab itself when I place a certain post inside the _posts folder. When I take this specific post out, the problem is resolved. The blog post itself works properly and I'm not encountering other issues. I'm running Minimal Mistakes theme and I'm knitting `.Rmd` reports in RStudio with GitHub flavored markdown.

[image]

[Link to my main repo](https://github.com/mkruisbrink/mkruisbrink.github.io) 
[Link to the specific post inside repo](https://github.com/mkruisbrink/mkruisbrink.github.io/blob/main/_posts/2022-11-11-explore-data-visualisation.md) 
[Link to config.yml](https://github.com/mkruisbrink/mkruisbrink.github.io/blob/main/_config.yml)

#### YAML header for knitting .Rmd

```yaml
title: "Data visualisation"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  md_document:
    variant: gfm
```

#### Knitting options for Rmd

```
library(knitr)

# macOS
# setwd("~/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/_reports/R-for-data-science/01-explore/01-data-visualisation/")

# Windows
setwd("D:/Max Kruisbrink/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/_reports/R-for-data-science/01-explore/")


knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())

# define knitr paths for macOS
#base.dir <- "~/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/"

# define knitr paths for Windows
base.dir <- "D:/Max Kruisbrink/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/"

base.url <- "/"
fig.path <- "assets/reports/R-for-data-science/01-explore/01-data-visualisation/"

# set knitr parameters
opts_knit$set(base.dir = base.dir, base.url = base.url)
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = fig.path)
```

I get a neat `.md` file which I can place inside my `_posts` folder with some yaml header. All other posts are processed fine, the error only appears when I place this specific post inside the folder.

#### YAML header for post

```yaml
title: "The basics of data visualisation in R"
excerpt: "These are the basics of visualizing data in R, using only the tidyverse functionality"
header:
  overlay_image: /assets/images/midjourney-optimised/big-computer-screen-financial-dashoard-optimised.jpg
category: 
  - Exploration
```

### What I've tried so far

I've tried the following:

- Spent at least 2 hours on online research, didn't find any proper relevant sources to help me out here
- Manually removing from and adding back all posts from the `_posts` folder to figure out the problem lies with this specific post
- Running `bundle update` and `bundle install`
- Double checking YAML headers for posts and the config file
- Checking `.Rmd` settings for other reports that are knitted in the same way and cause no issues
- Removing the post content from the `.md` file to see if the bug came from something in the code perhaps
- Replacing the whole YAML header with that of a post that causes no issues
- Ran `--trace` in combination with `bundle exec jekyll serve` for the same conflict results
- Ran `--verbose` in combination with `bundle exec jekyll serve` and I could find ***ONE*** extra instance of something writing `index.html` to `_site`. So the following appears twice in the log. I know the culprit is this post but how to get more info on what is causing it?

```
Writing: D:/Max Kruisbrink/Developer/mkruisbrink.github.io/_site/index.html
```

### Conclusions and questions

I'm starting to run out of options for my current skill level of debugging.

- Could it be something relating to `_includes` or `_layouts`? I might have tweaked layouts but pretty sure I left the includes folder alone. But why would other posts be unaffected?
- Could it be plugin related? I had no problems up until last week suddenly and didn't change any plugin.
- Should I update to the latest theme, removing any customization I've done to rule that out
- I'm running this in my gemspec

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"
gemspec

    gem "webrick"
    gem "jekyll-remote-theme"
    gem "tzinfo" #windows dependancy?  
    gem "tzinfo-data"
```

Can someone point me in a direction here? Getting slightly clueless and I want to be a little cautious with my re-rolling. Thanks in advance!

Edit 2022-12-28

When I remove the `permalink: \` from the main `index.html` file, the error is resolved but when building the site with `bundle exec jekyll serve` a strange `page2` folder is created in `_site` with its own `index.html`

However, I still think something is off with certain posts as the error is resolved when I move them to `_drafts`.

Anyone any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the `_config.yml` file where I was mixing liquid syntax and the pagination plugin.

```
# Outputting
permalink: pretty
paginate: 5 # amount of posts to show
paginate_path: /page:num/
timezone: Europe/Amsterdam # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones


# Plugins (previously gems:)
plugins:
  - jekyll-paginate
```

changing the outputting into the following solved my issue.

```
# Outputting
permalink: /:categories/:title/
timezone: Europe/Amsterdam # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
```

My final cue was the `page2` folder that was being built and the fact that EVERY post that I added to my `_posts` folder above the number 5 was causing issues.